# Instance of custom reusable html object

Tags: jquery, html, custom-controls

How to create custom `html` that i can reuse, actually i want to create something like this:

```
<script>
    // Menu Definition
    var menu = {
       p1: "0",
       p2: true,
       value: "test",
       setValue: function (value) {
            this.value=value;
       },
       getValue: function () {
            return value;
       },
       html: "<span class='p1'>"+p1+"</span>"+
             "<span class='p2'>"+p2+"</span>"


   }
   // Adding instance 
   $("#menu1").add(new menu());
   $("#menu2").add(new menu());

</script>
<html>
     <body>
          // Define menu containers
          <div id="menu1"></div>
          <div id="menu2"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to create a simple jQuery plugin. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to create object that will keep some internal values that are not shown on any element in their text field

Comment: jQuery Plugins usually work by saving a reference to the class instance (object) into the `data` of the element it connects to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems complicated, how about just using a function with arguments

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function menu(p1, p2) {
                var $p1 = $('<span />', {'class': 'p1', text: p1}),
                    $p2 = $('<span />', {'class': 'p2', text: p2});

                return $p1.add($p2);
            }

            $(function() {
                $("#menu1").append(menu(0, 'test'));
                $("#menu2").append(menu(1, 'something'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="menu1"></div>
        <div id="menu2"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7k4R/)

or you could turn that into a jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.menu = function(p1, p2) {
    var $p1 = $('<span />', {'class': 'p1', text: p1}),
        $p2 = $('<span />', {'class': 'p2', text: p2});

    this.append($p1.add($p2));
}

$(function() {
    $("#menu1").menu(0, 'test');
    $("#menu2").menu(1, 'something');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7k4R/2/)

Comment: I want to create object that will keep some internal values that are not shown on any element in their text field, something like class in Java with private properties, if its possible...

Comment: jQuery's data() will do that, you don't really need classes and instances, but whatever floats your goat I suppose ?